# Merge two maps to resultant Map in Groovy

Tags: collections, groovy

I have two maps as:

```
firstMap = [totalProjectCount:53, activeProjectCount:29, completedProjectCount:1, userCount:85]
secondMap = [totalProjectCount:48, activeProjectCount:41, completedProjectCount:0, userCount:123]
```

and i need result such as:

```
resultMap = [totalProjectCount:101, activeProjectCount:70, completedProjectCount:1, userCount:208]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map additionJoin( Map firstMap, Map secondMap )
{
  def resultMap = [:];
  resultMap.putAll( firstMap );
  resultMap.putAll( secondMap );

  resultMap.each { key, value ->
    if( firstMap[key] && secondMap[key] )
    {
      resultMap[key] = firstMap[key] + secondMap[key]
    }
  }

  return resultMap;
}

def firstMap = [totalProjectCount:53, activeProjectCount:29, completedProjectCount:1, userCount:85]
def secondMap = [totalProjectCount:48, activeProjectCount:41, completedProjectCount:0, userCount:123]


def resultMap = additionJoin( firstMap , secondMap  )

println resultMap
```

Answer (score 4):

Yet another Groovy alternative:

```
def firstMap = [totalProjectCount:53, activeProjectCount:29, completedProjectCount:1, userCount:85, a:1]
def secondMap = [totalProjectCount:48, activeProjectCount:41, completedProjectCount:0, userCount:123, b:2]

def result = [firstMap, secondMap]*.keySet().flatten().toSet().collectEntries { k ->
    [k, (firstMap[k] ?: 0) + (secondMap[k] ?: 0)]
}

assert result == [a:1, b:2, completedProjectCount:1, userCount:208, activeProjectCount:70, totalProjectCount:101]
```

This also works if you have values in one map that don't exist in the other (see `a` and `b`)

Comment: Nice answer. Just to understand it, keyset gives keyset of both the maps and .flatten unites them to a set using toSet and collectEntries just collect these as Map. Right?

Comment: @VinayPrajapati Yep :-)

Answer (score 3):

To make this a reusable part of your toolbelt, it's important, to extract the function you want to merge with.

The merging itself is then just the creation of a new map with all the keys of the maps and the values reduced with the passed function.

```
Map mergeWith(Closure fn, Map... maps) {
    maps*.keySet().sum().collectEntries{k->
        [k, maps.findAll{it.containsKey k}*.get(k).inject(fn)]
    }
}

def m1 = [a:53, b:29, c:1, x:85]
def m2 = [a:48, b:41, c:0, y:123]
def m3 = [z:42]

// sum
assert mergeWith({a,b->a+b}, m1, m2, m3)==[a:101, b:70, c:1, x:85, y:123, z:42]
// product
assert mergeWith({a,b->a*b}, m1, m2, m3)==[a:2544, b:1189, c:0, x:85, y:123, z:42]
```

#### edit: as requested in the comments, some explanations

`mergeWith` takes a reducing function (a function, that gets called with
two params and returns one value) and some maps.  This means, you can a)
use it for other operations than just the sum and b) you can use it for
more than one map.

`maps*.keySet().sum()` is the union of all keys.  Then we
`collectEntries` (build a new map) over that set of keys.  For the value
find all maps, that contains the key (this makes this work nicely even
in cases, where the actual value is falsey) and fetch the values of `k`
via the spread operator.  Then we reduce (oddly named `inject`) the list
of values with the passed function.

Comment: Good answer. @Cfrick could you please explain it a bit more as I myself just understood a part of it.

Comment: ya sure @cfrick please little bit of explanation is required for me too

Comment: sure can do, but what parts do you have problems with?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Map<String, Integer> resultMap = new HashMap<>(firstMap);       
secondMap.forEach((k, v) -> resultMap.merge(k, v, Integer::sum));
```

Comment: Merge method is built in or we have to define the logic because i cannot find it ?

Answer (score 1):

More efficiently, you could write it like below:

```
Map additionJoin(Map firstMap, Map secondMap)
{
  secondMap.each { key, value ->
    if( firstMap[key])
    {
      firstMap[key] = firstMap[key] + secondMap[key]
    }
  }

  return firstMap;
}
 def firstMap = [totalProjectCount:53, activeProjectCount:29, completedProjectCount:1, userCount:85]
    def secondMap = [totalProjectCount:48, activeProjectCount:41, completedProjectCount:0, userCount:123]


    def resultMap additionJoin( firstMap , secondMap  )

     println resultMap
```

This would be high in performance as it would save using a third map.

Also, if you understand value by reference you can do it like below as well:

```
void additionJoin(Map firstMap, Map secondMap)
{
  secondMap.each { key, value ->
    if( firstMap[key])
    {
      firstMap[key] = firstMap[key] + secondMap[key]
    }
  }
}

def firstMap = [totalProjectCount:53, activeProjectCount:29, completedProjectCount:1, userCount:85]
def secondMap = [totalProjectCount:48, activeProjectCount:41, completedProjectCount:0, userCount:123]


 additionJoin( firstMap , secondMap  )

 println firstMap
```

Though later solution hampers the readability (have opinionated view) which could be achieved by additional statement as below:

> def resultMap  = firstMap

Hope it helps you do the same efficiently.

Comment: Avoiding a third map does not equate to "high in performance"

Comment: @tim_yates but you would be saving time and space for creating a new Map object and then adding values to it.Which could prove substantial if map ha millions of k-v pairs. Hope It makes sense.

Comment: Of course I understand. My issues are that a) What performance gain could be had? (I guess minimal) b) This then makes the code mutate the original map, so possibly breaks any form of concurrency you may wish to add at a later date.  Without measuring a) however, or knowing if it might break b), it's hard to say.  But blindly calling "high in performance" without any sort of measurement or caveats isn't helpful, and just propagates this sort of cargo-cult premature optimisation