# Merging two maps with lists inside in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am struggling to solve the following task:
There are two maps with lists inside:

```
def m1 = [ k1: [ l1: ['s1', 's2']]]
def m2 = [ k1: [ l1: ['s3', 's4']]]
```

As a result I want to have single map with lists added together.

```
assert merge(m1, m2) == [ k1: [ l1: ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4']]]
```

In practice the maps are much bigger but idea is the same. Can anyone help?

Comment: The keys are fixed or could be any keys?

Comment: The keys are the same but map2 can contain only few keys from map1. Nesting is always the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add two maps in Groovy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129837/add-two-maps-in-groovy) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326587/merge-two-maps-to-resultant-map-in-groovy

Answer (score 3):

10 mins of experimenting in groovy console brought this code up:

```
def m1 = [ k1: [ l1: ['s1', 's2']]]
def m2 = [ k1: [ l1: ['s3', 's4']]]

def accumulator = [:].withDefault{ [:].withDefault{ [] } }

Closure merger
merger = { Map trg, Map m ->
  m.each{ k, v ->
    switch( v ){
      case Map: merger trg[ k ], v; break
      case List: trg[ k ].addAll v; break
    }
  }
}

[ m1, m2 ].each merger.curry( accumulator )

assert [ k1: [ l1: ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4']]] == accumulator
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I've thrown together that uses [Map's `collectEntries` method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#collectEntries(groovy.lang.Closure)). We use it twice: the first time finds the sub-maps that exist in `m2` that need to be merged. The second time finds the list values that need to be combined.

```
def m1 = [ k1: [ l1: ['s1', 's2']], k2: [l2: ['s5', 's6']]] // include entry not in m2
def m2 = [ k1: [ l1: ['s3', 's4']]]

/* Assumes that the maps contain values that support the + operator */
def combineListMaps = { map1, map2 ->
    map1.collectEntries { key, list -> 
        def list2 = map2[key] ?: []
        [key, list + list2]
    } 
}

m1.collectEntries { key, listMap ->
    def listMap2 = m2[key]
    if (listMap2) 
        [key, combineListMaps(listMap, listMap2)] 
    else
        [key, listMap] 
}
```